# Run pythod code with Django and produce output on web

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I know this could be a repeated question for many of you but I have not been able to find a proper answer for this yet. I am a beginner to Django and Python. I have a python code which runs and produce output on cli at present but I want the same program to run its output on web.

I read that for web django is best suitable framework and for this purpose I started to study django. I see in every tutorial people have discussed apps, views urls etc but not seen an example which integrate a python code with django.

All I am looking for to understand how can I integrate my python script with Django and where do I place my code in Django project or app. Should I import it within views? if yes, then how to present my output to web.

Here is the sample code I am running, it basically opens two files and run some regex to extract the desired information.

```
import re


def vipPoolFileOpen():          # function opens vip and pool config file and store them to vip_config and pool_config variables
    with open("pool_config.txt",'rb') as pool_config:
        pool_config = pool_config.read()
        pool_config = pool_config.split('ltm')
    with open("vip_config.txt",'rb') as vip_config:
        vip_config = vip_config.read()
        vip_config = vip_config.split('ltm')
    return vip_config,pool_config



def findWidth(vip_config):  # function to find the maximum length of vip in entire file, this will be used to adjust column space
    colWidth=0
    for item in vip_config:
        i=0
        if colWidth<len(item):
            while i<len(vip_config)-1:
                if len(item)>=len(vip_config[i+1]):
                    colWidth=len(item)
                    i=i+1
                else:
                    i+=1
                    continue
    return colWidth

def regexFunction():
    vip_config, pool_config = vipPoolFileOpen()
    findWidth(vip_config)
    for vip in vip_config:
        regVip = re.compile(r'pool (.+)\r')
        poolByVip = regVip.findall(vip)     # poolByVip holds pool name from the vip_config file
        for poolblock in pool_config:
            regPool = re.compile(r'pool (.+) {')
            poolByConfig = regPool.findall(poolblock)
            if poolByVip == poolByConfig:
                print vip + poolblock
                break
            elif poolByVip == ['none']:
                print vip
                break
            else:
                continue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should present your output to the web via view. You need to write a view function (or a class view) in views.py and provide an url where you want to have it in urls.py

If you rewrite your function to return desired result instead of printing it, tou can do the following:

write this in views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from wherever_you_have_it import regexFunction

def bar(request):
    result = regexFunction()  # result should be a string
    return HttpResponse(result)
```

and in urls.py:

```
from .views import bar

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^foo$', bar),
]
```

Providing of course you have created your Django app at the first place.

Your result should be displayed as plain text on address localhost:8000/foo - but you need to:

```
python menage.py runserver
```

In your terminal first

And of course feel free to look at:
https://github.com/Ergaro/CheckMyChords
to see how a simple django app looks like

Comment: Thank you for the reply here!
it did help me